# Getting ring 0 mode in C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows

How I can get ring 0 operating mode for my process in Windows 7(or Vista)?

Comment: ask yourself: should I really be writing a ring 0 kernal process?

Comment: Actually, tell us why you want to run in ring 0 and we'll tell you whether it is a good solution or not.

Comment: @Mitch: Look up KERNAL in Wikipedia. It is a misspelling.

Comment: see [Accessing ring 0 mode from user applications ( and why Borland allows this )](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37455498/2521214)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Allowing arbitrary code to run in ring 0 violates basic OS security principles.

Only the OS kernel and device drivers run in ring 0. If you want to write ring 0 code, write a Windows device driver. [This](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/foundation/DrvDev_Intro.mspx) may be helpful.

Certain security holes may allow your code to run in ring 0 also, but this isn't portable because the hole might be fixed in a patch :P

Comment: How I can write a Windows device driver?

Answer (score 7):

Technically speaking, all processes have some threads spending some of their time in Kernel-Mode (ring 0). Whenever a user-mode process makes a syscall into the OS, there is a transition where the thread gets into ring 0 via a 'gate'. Whenever a process needs to talk to a device, allocate more process-wide memory, or spawn new threads, a syscall is used to ask the OS to provide this service.

Therefore, if you want to have a process run some code in ring 0, you'll need to write a driver and then communicate with this driver thru some syscalls. The most common syscall for this is called ioctl (stands for I/O Control).

Another thing to look at on the Windows platform is the UMDF (User-Mode Driver Framework). This allows you to write, debug, and test a driver in user-mode (running in ring 3) but it is still accessible to other drivers or other processes in the system.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set kernel mode from a user mode process. That's how security works.