# Running in kernel mode on x86 W7

Tags: windows-7, x86, kernel

I'm curious about how, running Windows 7 on x86, you could execute some code in kernel mode. This is for my own personal use; so I'm not bothered about giving Windows a trillion permissions or whatever. Does kernel mode code have to be specially compiled or linked? etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ring 0 mode in C++ (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417121/getting-ring-0-mode-in-c-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only code from the kernel itself, and from certain device drivers, can run in kernel (supervisor, [ring 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29)) mode.

So you will have to write a device driver.

EDIT: [the question has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417121/getting-ring-0-mode-in-c-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Ring 0 drivers can execute code in kernel mode.

You will need Windows Device Driver Kit for such development.

Also you have to be extremely careful with driver development because unhandled exception occurring in the kernel indicates a serious bug that exists in the operating system or (more likely) in a device driver and not in an application. Once memory in the kernel gets potentially corrupt, it isn't safe for the system to continue running and you see what is typically called "the Blue Screen of Death."

So normally your drivers should be WHQL certified.